# config file of shell complete

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, auto-completion

I want add autocompletion to my script.
I wrote bash code for autocomplete (using this tutor http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) and put it to `/etc/bash_completion.d/`
then i execute in bash `complete -F _main_complete -o filenames ./script.sh`
and it's works.

But after reboot I need write this command again.

Sure I can add this to `.bashrc`, but it looks bad. Where config file for `complete` located?

Comment: I can use me bash file for `complete` options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that, for a login shell,

1. `/etc/profile` will source
2. `/etc/profile.d/bash_completions.sh`, which will source
3. `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, which will source
4. `~/.bash_completion`

assuming all those files exist and are readable.

Put your own completions in `~/.bash_completion`